# Insert returns error: (sub-select returns 6 columns - expected 1)

Tags: sqlite

I have a table SIGHTINGS(NAME, PERSON, LOCATION, SIGHTED), and I'm trying to insert a new row into that table with the following query:

```
INSERT INTO SIGHTINGS (NAME, PERSON, LOCATION, SIGHTED)
VALUES ('Douglas dustymaiden', 'Person B', 'Double Mountain', '2005-11-28');
```

But it's returning this error:

```
[2017-12-04 17:08:18] [1] [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (sub-select returns 6 columns - expected 1)
```

I've looked up the correct syntax for sqlite inserts [here](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-insert/), and from what I can tell, the insert is written correctly. Can someone tell me why it's throwing this error instead of doing the insert? I'm using DataGrip 2017 if that helps identify any issues.

EDIT:

Here's the trigger I added to the database. The insert works without the trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER SightingLocationError
  BEFORE INSERT ON SIGHTINGS
  FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN NEW.LOCATION NOT IN FEATURES
BEGIN
  SELECT RAISE(ABORT, 'Error: Insert into the SIGHTINGS table references location that is not found in the database.');
END;
```

Comment: We cannot help you if you keep the trigger a secret.

Comment: @CL. I didn't know that the trigger would be causing the error. I tested it on a copy of the database without the trigger, but it still threw the same error. I'll post the trigger above.

Comment: @CL. Sorry, I copied the wrong database when I tested it. The insert works without the trigger present.

Comment: @CL. If was my trigger throwing the error, wouldn't it print out the error message from the RAISE(ABORT, 'message') function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHEN NEW.LOCATION NOT IN FEATURES
```

The `FEATURES` table has six columns, so the database does not know how it should search for the location value.

Use an explicit subquery to return the column you want to use for this:

```
WHEN NEW.LOCATION NOT IN (SELECT xxx FROM FEATURES)
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I should have noticed that. Been staring at this screen for too long lol